# how to use redirect react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The user is in home page and if he goes to any protected route(cart page, profile page) without authentication he will be  Redirecting to login page and after login they must not return to home page, they must go to the current location they were trying to go to when they were redirected, but it returns to the homepage.

```
 <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} />
        <Route path='/signin' element={<SignInScreen />} />
        <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUpScreen />} />
        <Route path='/products/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path='/cart' element={<CartScreen />} />
          <Route path='/wishlist' element={<WishlistScreen />} />
          <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfileScreen />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
```

```
const PrivateRoute = () => {
    if (!auth.authenticated) {
      return <Navigate to='/signin' replace={true} />;
    }
    return <Outlet />;
  };
```

```
 const Submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = { email, password };

    if (!email || !password) {
      setMessage('Please Enter All Fields');
    } else {
      setLoading(true);
      return await axios
        .post('/signin', data)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.message === 'Invalid Credentials') {
            setMessage('Invalid Credentials');
            setLoading(false);
          }
          if (res.data.message === 'Logged In') {
            setLoading(false);
            navigate('/', { replace: true });
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the private route you should grab the current `location` to send in route state to the log in page, and upon successful authentication, redirect them back to the location they were originally attempting to access.

```
import { ...., useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  ...

  if (!auth.authenticated) {
    return <Navigate to='/signin' replace state={{ from: location }} />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};
```

In the `SignIn` component, access the `from` value from the `location` object.

```
import { ...., useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const SignIn = () => {
  const { state: { from = "/" } = {} } = useLocation();

  ...

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { email, password };

    if (!email || !password) {
      setMessage('Please Enter All Fields');
    } else {
      setLoading(true);
      return axios
        .post('/signin', data)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.message === 'Invalid Credentials') {
            setMessage('Invalid Credentials');
          }
          if (res.data.message === 'Logged In') {
            navigate(from, { replace: true }); // <-- redirect to from value
          }
        })
        .catch(console.log)
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  };

  ...
```